# Notation for selecting a number of columns from a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $$\mathbf{M} = \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c & d \\ e & f & g& h\end{pmatrix}$$

and $$S =\{ 1, 3, 4 \}.$$

I would like to find an elegant notation to define a selection function to generate the submatrix $$\mathbf{M}_2 = \begin{pmatrix} a & c & d \\ e & g& h\end{pmatrix}$$

by keeping all of the $\mathbf{M}$ columns included in $S$. I was thinking about using the projection function, but I am not sure how to extend it for this setting.

I would also benefit from good references.

Answer (score 0):

You could multiply by the appropriate matrix on the right, like
$$M_2 = M \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

You could also just make up your own notation in words, similar to what you've already written in your post.